# Does “snatch something over” or “snatch something away” sound native?

Tags: phrases, speech

I’ve learnt that you can say things like:

> She snatched the biscuit out of his hand. (snatch ... out of)
>   She snatched a biscuit from the plate. (snatch ... from)

But how does it sound if I say something like:

> She walked up and snatched that biscuit over/away.

Is it correct grammar? Does it make sense to native speakers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"snatch over" doesn't exist. You can use "away" with snatch. But it is only used as an addition, when you use "to snatch from". So, your example would become:

> She walked up and snatched that biscuit away from him.